# View part of Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I am reading the [Developing a Spring Framework MVC application step-by-step](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/) specifically the [Create the View](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html#step1.10) section.

It uses hello.jsp.

I am new with this. I assume that we can use the View part any client framework like GWT, jQueryUI, etc. without using JSP.

Correct?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Spring integrates with several view technologies out of the box, and it's built to be extensible. Check out "[Resolving views with the ViewResolver interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver)" for an overview and list of common view implementations. To use some view technology, you have to have a [ViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ViewResolver.html) implementation for it.

Comment: Thanks. I just found this http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=8159#aMVC.